# How do I release 25 ether from a Wallet Contract I accidentally created a few months back?

Tags: ether, wallets, mist, recovery

When I first started with Mist, I sent 25 ether to a Wallet Contract. It showed up on Mist for a few weeks and disappeared.

I see the transaction here: [0x7de54cbb5ab805bfbb96014f415799712d5ada35](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7de54cbb5ab805bfbb96014f415799712d5ada35)

Can I send the 25 ether to my main wallet? I have the password.

Does this need to be done in my Mac's Terminal?

Comment: Is the issue that you no longer see the wallet in Mist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import a wallet into Mist through the "Add Wallet" option. Just click the "Import Wallet" button, and enter the address of your wallet. You should then be able to send from that wallet as usual.

[image: Add Wallet]

[image: Import Wallet]

Note that the wallet you import should be from the `Ethereum` or `.ethereum` directory, `keystore` subdirectory, located here:

- Mac: `~/Library/Ethereum`
- Linux: `~/.ethereum`
- Windows: `%APPDATA%/Ethereum`

[More details on backing up a wallet](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/account-management.html#backup-and-restore-accounts).

Comment: Thank you. It says I don't own the account. When I go into terminal and put the keystore/private key in it says "no such file or directory"... Again, thank you for your help but I think those 25 eth are gone ...

Comment: So you don't own the key used to create the wallet? Did you delete your keystore folder?

Comment: Ive got the keystore: UTC--2016-01-28T18-08-23.319926174Z--1fca.....

Comment: In order to access your Ether, you'll need access to account 0xf5026d595eeba7ece5cfef4e531b9bfb22f8a0c6. If you don't have that private key, there's no way to  retrieve you funds

Comment: Thank you Tjaden. I backed up the keystore and thought the number after "UTC--2016-01-28T18-08-23.319926174Z-- was my private key. Guess its gone... Thank you for all your help : )

Comment: The number after the UTC... is your address, the private key is inside. If you backed up all of the UTC.... files, you should still have the proper private key....

Comment: I did back it up. These are the files in my back Mist up: Cache, Cookies, Cookies-journal, Databases, DevTools Extensions, GPU Cache, IndexedDB, Local Storage, Network, Node, Node.log, Node.log.0 - 4, {reference, QuotaManager, QuotaManager-

Comment: I had a similar problem and I was able to import my private key here: https://www.myetherwallet.com/